# web2py - Unit testing @auth.requires_login()

Tags: python, unit-testing, web2py, python-unittest

All,

I have created a unit test for my web2py app.

I mainly followed this slice: http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1465/unittesting-doctesting-and-userinterface-testing

I can register and login users with tests.

I cannot however get around the problem of testing the auth.requires_login() decorator.

I run tests that log the user in, i can see the resultant changes to the test db in auth_events and auth_users, but attempts to open the index function result in redirect.

When I run the test with the @auth decorator removed and put a simple if statement to check if a user exists i.e. that i logged a user in.  This shows that a user exists and the auth object is visible to the function.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: I don't see why I got a negative vote.

Comment: I solved it, am I am wrong but there seems to be a serious lack of information regarding unit testing.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as answer? Or was it a trivial thing (e.g. a typo), in which case we might just close the question.

Comment: I added the code in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the setup for unittest.  The error I made was where I placed the execution of execfile command.

```html
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        global auth, request, session, response, db

        self._application = 'contacts'
        self._controller = 'default'

        self._pyfile = os.path.join(request.env.web2py_path, request.folder, 'controllers', self._controller + '.py')

        self.db_link = 'postgres://......._test'

        db = test_helpers.copy_db(globals(), db_link=self.db_link)
        db.commit()

        current.request = Request(globals())

        current.session = Session()

        current.request.application = self._application
        current.request.controller = self._controller

        auth = Auth(globals(), db)

        auth.define_tables()

        db(db.contacts.id > 0).delete()  # Clear the database
        db.commit()

        # clear all users from auth tables and commit changes
        db(db.auth_user.id > 0).delete()  # Clear the database
        db.commit()

        # execute the controller file, passing in the env globals.
        execfile(self._pyfile, globals())
```

A follow-up:

This set-up works fine I can register, and enter @auth protected functions in the controller file.

However now the problem is that I cannot call auth.logout() with a successful logout.  I debugged it and it seems that auth object is not updated until after a redirect.  Is there some way to get around this??